# Grouping Months Echos Missing Last Month Variables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the output grouped by month using PHP and MYSQL. With some help from stack before I was provided a simple solution.

```
if ($last_month != $month) {
    $monthDiv = "<div class='monthSalute'>$month</div>";
    $last_month = "$month";
} else {
    $monthDiv = "";

}
```

Easy enough and it made a lot of sense. The only problem is the month variable and `$last_month` are skipping every once in a while. To explain I did some var dump for last month and month. Notice the skipped month.

```
string(8) "December"
string(8) "December"


string(7) "January"
string(7) "January"


string(0) ""
string(0) ""


string(7) "January"
string(7) "January"


string(5) "March"
string(5) "March"


string(5) "April"
string(5) "April"
```

This ends up with an output like this:

```
**December -- header**

dec1 - game

dec5 - game 

dec31 - game 


**January -- header**

jan4 - game 

jan7 - game 

jan26 - game 

**January -- header**

jan27 - game 

jan31 - game
```

It should be

```
**January -- header**

jan4 - game 

jan7 - game 

jan26 - game 


jan27 - game 
jan31 - game
```

Notice there is no second January Header.

Here is the full code as a reference.

```
<?php
// Check to see the URL variable is set and that it exists in the database
// Connect to the MySQL database
include "../../includes/db_conx.php"; 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$sqlcount = "SELECT * FROM discounts WHERE team='cyoram' ORDER BY date ASC";

$sql_countRam = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sqlcount);
$calCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql_count); 

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if ($calCount > 0) {
// get all the product details
 $x=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_countRam)){
    $id = $row["id"];
    $opponent = $row["opponent"];
    $team = $row["team"];
    $notes = $row["notes"]; 
    $month = $row["month"];
    $buyLink = $row["buyLink"];
    $time = $row["time"];
    $date = $row["date"];
    $formatted_date = date("l d F Y H:i A", strtotime($date));
    $raw = "$formatted_date";
    $xplod = explode(' ',$raw);
    /* \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ */
    include "includes/logos.php"; 
    /* \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ */
    $classCssRam = "inline-block";
    $x++; 
    $classChangeRam = ($x%2 == 0)? 'whiteBackground': 'grayBackground';
    /* Print month heading for new month */
    if ($last_month != $month) {
        $monthDiv = "<div class='monthSalute'>$month</div>";
        $last_month = "$month";
    } else {
        $monthDiv = "";
    }
    $product_listRam .= "  
   <div class='aNew' style='clear:both;display:$classCssRam;'>
   $monthDiv

    <table width='400px' border='0'>
                <tr class='$classChangeRam'>
                    <td rowspan='2' class='date' >$xplod[1]</td>
                    <td class='day'>$xplod[0]</td>
                 <td rowspan='2' class='centerLogo'><div class='containImgPos'><img src='$imgLogo' height='32px' style='position:relative;left:$posImgR;' /></div></td>
                    <td class='city'>$city</td>
                    <td rowspan='2' class='butt_pad'><a href='calendar_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> &bull; <a href='calendar_list.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class='$classChangeRam'>
                    <td class='time $classChangeRam'>$time</td>
                    <td class='opponent $classChangeRam'>$opponent</td>
              </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
";
}}
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the data in the database is correct, all rows have months?

Comment: @jeroen Yes, they do all have months. I'm puzzled as to what may be happening. It's almost as if it times out or something. I don't think it would happen on every refresh though.

Comment: You should do a complete `var_dump()` of the row that gives you the empty month as the problem seems to be with that row.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @jeroen How would you target just that row? I'm not sure which row it is signalling.

Comment: Just dump them all...